# "in each side" or "in each sides"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

If I want to say that there are two people and each one of them is found in other side of the house. What is the correct way to say it?

> 1) There are two people in each side of the house
>
> 2) There are two people in each side**s** of the house

And by the way (in the same topic), are the two following sentences equal to the previous two - in the aspect of the meaning?

> 1) There is one person in each side of the house.
>
> 2) There is one person in each sides of the house.

Comment: *Each* and *every* are distributive; you're considering each side individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Two people on each side* means *two people on this side and two people on that side*—four people in all (if there are two sides).

What you mean is *one person on each* side, one on this side and one on that.

If you have not already explained that two sides are involved, you need to say so explicitly:

> There is one person on each of the two sides.  *OR*
>   There are two people, one on each of the two sides.

Comment: By the way, is it always "on"  each side or it depends on the context?  (For example: "there are two bones in the face, one ON each of the sides"

Comment: @Assiduous *On* is usual with sides of anything: houses, walls, borders, &c. *In* is OK if the situation you are describing might be misunderstood as referring to the outside of the house, but ordinarily you will have provided a context which will make clear that you are speaking of "partitioning" an interior space.

Comment: @Assiduous English is odd - you have to be careful.  You ride ***on** the bus* (not ***in** the bus*), and you sit ***on** the left side of the bus*, but you would also say that you *go for a ride **in** the car*, even though you would sit ***on** the right side of the car*.  The rules aren't always clear.  `Where is Joe?`  : `He's in the house, on this side`

Answer (score 2):

*Each* is used before a singular noun and a singular verb/pronoun is used for it.

> Each **item** **consists** of 10 questions. (if there are two items, there are 20 questions)
>
> Each of these people **has** some useful talent.
>
> Each component can be replaced separately if **it** breaks.

As the comments point, you're considering each item individually. Then:

> There is one person on each side